# JavaScript onkeydown not functioning

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to setup a text box that runs a function on keydown.

The code is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('Input_Number');
input.addEventListener('onkeypress', DrawDigits);

function DrawDigits(event) {

    if (event && event.keyCode == '13') {}
}
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wuK4G/

I know this is a common question, but I really can't find the answer. I've tried several methods and none of them work.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right Fiddle there?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have this code in it?

Comment: I don't think its the correct fiddle, Also, why is there a keypress in the code ?

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery if you **are** using jQuery?

Comment: I am using jQuery. It's the right fiddle. The event listener is at line 24. The function is at line 31. I threw an alert in there to see if it works.

Comment: @Jamil Why don't you use jQuery's event listeners?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function DrawDigits(event) {
    if (event && event.keyCode == '13') {}
}

var input = document.getElementById('Input_Number');
input.addEventListener('keypress', DrawDigits);
//                      ^^
```

The eventlistener is `keypress` instead of `onkeypress`.

If you assign the eventlistener without `addEventListener` it is:

```
document.getElementById('Input_Number').onkeypress = DrawDigits
```

Maybe that was the confusion?

Comment: That worked. I'll select it as the correct answer. I could've sworn I tried that method, but apparently I didn't. Thanks.